# My Sessions as Client and Admin are messed up

Tags: session-state

I'm currently creating a small project where I built a front website and another one as a dashboard. When the normal user is signing up, I create SESSION with 3 parameters : `$_SESSION['id']`,  `$_SESSION['name']` and  `$_SESSION['connected']`(boolean). The same when I log as ADMIN in the DASHBOARD, it creates SESSION with 3 parameters : `$_SESSION['id']`,  `$_SESSION['name']` and  `$_SESSION['admin_connected']`(boolean).

ADMIN and USER are located in 2 different tables in Myslqi.
Here's the code:

```php
if (password_verify($_POST['password'],$password)) {
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['admin_connected']=TRUE;
    $_SESSION['id']=$id;
    $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['username'];

    header('location: home.php');
}
```

**How I check in the admin  DASHBOARD profile pages:**

```php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin_connected'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
```

**How I check in the CLIENT pages:**

```php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_connected'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
```

It works when I am not connected and try to get straight to the Profile page. But it somehow interferes with USER session cookies. If My problem is, when I log into the ADMIN Dashboard using an Admin account created in a different Database Table, **the $_SESSION['name'] of USER ACCOUNT is messed up with `$_SESSION['name']`** in ADMIN ACCOUNT. As a navigate through my DASHBOARD, the ADMIN username changes to the USER username. When I log out, I log out automatically in both sides.

I tried to use different names of the SESSION Variables of both. but the problem persists.

WHERE AM I WRONG? Do YOU HAVE any solution? Thanks in Advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than different names, Given what you have, I'd do something like `$_SESSION['login_type'] = ['user', 'admin']` if someone is a user AND an admin. Or I'd do `$_SESSION['admin'] = [/*name, id, connected*/]` & `$_SESSION['user'] = [...]`

In your user profile page, at the top, you could do:

```php
$admin = $_SESSION['admin'] ?? false; //using if isset is so many keystrokes!
if(!$user||!$admin['connected']) {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 403 Forbidden",true,403);
    echo "You are not logged in &amp; cannot view this page";
    return; //or exit, if your server doesn't have any cleanup code, like logging, to run
}
```

I'm not sure I have enough information to properly provide a solution. But from what you've shared, it looks like you're only doing redirects, not actually checking permissions on each given page.

Comment: Hi Reed. Thanks a lot for your answer. Very helpful indeed and I appreciate ! 

I realize what I was doing is only redirects as you say. Just because I didn't get the chance to learn about permissions yet. Would you recommend me any great course on checking  permissions and users privilege? Thanks man.

Comment: Also, may be I need to see other ways to handle Sessions other than this one I was doing. Next to my nav menu on top. I put something like "Hello, $_SESSION['username']. 

 I still don't understand how the USER username and the ADMIN use form the could be messed up? Yet I was using two different variable names.

Comment: :) I wish I did. I'm currently updating my own user library & permissions had been a big challenge, but I generally opt for thinking too much, figuring out everything on my own so... I don't look at a lot of tutorials. This isn't a wise approach, and I do recommend tutorials lol. Something I'm trying to get better about. I just don't know where to send you. You could look at pre-existing user libraries like [Sentinel](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0). I'm developing a [simpler version with a ui](https://github.com/Taeluf/PHP-User), but it's not ready to use.

Comment: There's als [UserFrosting](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting) that I checked out awhile ago, but didn't quite vibe with. It might be a good place to go. If you're trying write your own, these probably won't be much help... but their implementations could guide you. Existing CMSes like laravel & django & pretty much all have their own user & permissions systems built in, if you want to jump into a CMS.

Comment: You might be able to ask on reddit or reach out to code podcasters for advice. I listen to Hanselminutes w/ Scott Hanselman & SyntaxFM w/ Wes Bos & Scot Tolinski. None of them are PHP specific podcasts, but if you ask 'em on Twitter, they might be able to refer you.